# Is it correct that CoreGraphics doesn't handle 24-bit, but only 32-bit images?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm rendering an image to my context and then mess with it's pixels.
For my purpose I don't need an alpha channel.
The [Supported Pixel Formats Table](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB) tells me that I still have to use a fourth channel, also I get exceptions if I try otherwise.
Does this mean I have to waste 1/4th of the memory?

Answer (score 0):

Think of it not as wasting 1/4 your memory but as gaining valuable hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

It is not straight to complain about the spec, however you are not wasting anything. The image itself could be stored without alpha and the video and underlying libs need the alpha anyway. 
Or dou you want ios to remove the alpha? ;-)